# Create File on fly and upload it in SharePoint in C#

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I want to  write in MemoryStream and then put/ upload the same in Shared documents in Sharepoint Below is the code I am trying:-

```
 var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://server.info/");

                string fileUrl = "/Shared Documents/NewDocumentFromTemplate.txt";

                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                using (var file = new StreamWriter(ms))
                {

                    file.WriteLine("Wrinting in file");
                }

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, ms, true);
```

Its actually creating a new file as NewDocumentFromTemplate.txt but it is empty. Its not writing anything.  :(

Actuallly I want to create a file on fly and then upload it in share point.

Please help I am first time working with Share Point client.

Comment: You should probably use flush after WriteLine. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using Flush also   not helps.. Its still not writing in the file..

Comment: Thank you Madhur Ahuja.. Its actually works..

Answer (score 3):

Yes.. Flush actually works.. Thank you

```
                var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://server.info/");

                using (var memoryStrm = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStrm))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("sfdgfg");

                        writer.Flush();  //added flush
                        memoryStrm.Position = 0;

                        const string fileUrl = "/Shared Documents/NewDocumentFromTemplate.txt";

                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, memoryStrm, true);
                    }
                }
```